# Emails from community at stackexchange use markdown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, email

Markdown does not work in emails, so you should probably not use it in them. The email is still readable and the links work, they're just not at the place where you'd expect them to be.

[image: email]

Comment: I think most of the emailing interfaces for SE are in MarkDown (which is converted to HTML before being sent), at least the mod messaging one is, so something must've broken there. My leaderboard email for Astro worked [fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/stpHL.png)

Comment: @Manishearth My Tor Beta email was fine too, summat's just gone wrong with this one.

Comment: I bet that the email is sent in both plaintext and HTML alternatives, and your email client elected to show the plaintext version.

Comment: @Martijn Possibly. That particular client seems to always prefer plaintext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We send out emails with both HTML and text alternatives The markdown is included as plaintext (after all, it is *meant* to be a plaintext version of a rich text as well as a markup language...)

Please see the configuration of your MUA so the HTML version is preferred.